# How to make .exe files not trigger window/mac security warning?

Tags: python

I had developed a python program, converted it to a .exe, and decided to put it online for people to download. However, many of my friends told me that the Windows security screen popped up as soon as they attempted to run the file. Is there a method to prevent this?

Comment: no, you need authenticatation for your script into security database systems, otherwise windows defender or any antivirus will check it and make warning or prevent it from running directly

Answer (score 0):

You're not being very specific about the Windows error message, I'll just guess that Windows is blocking the file simply for being an executable.

If that's the case, you cannot prevent it, but it's easy for the person downloading it to fix: right-click on the downloaded file, choose `Properties`, and if there's a security warning at the bottom saying *"This file came from another computer [...]"*, check the `Unblock` box (see screenshot below).

[image]